# Unable to resolve module fs - react-native-dotenv

Tags: react-native, environment-variables, fs, dotenv

I am doing an online course about React-Native and Firebase but I came across an error.

Here it is : Error: Unable to resolve module fs from Documents/code/ChatApp/node_modules/react-native-dotenv/index.js:

[image]

I've seen responses that fs is not available on react-native, is that true ?

Why install a package so that in the end it can't be used?

thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1):

That online course might be referring to old version of `react-native-dotenv`. To make it work with the new version, make these minor changes to your code as explained in this [wiki](https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv/wiki/Migration-Guide). No need to install `fs`.

1. If you have a code like this

```
import { API_URL, API_TOKEN } from 'react-native-dotenv';
```

change it to

```
import { API_URL, API_TOKEN } from '@env';
```

2. Make sure `module:react-native-dotenv` is present in `babel.config.js` file. Example -

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  plugins: [
    "module:react-native-dotenv",
    ...
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-dotenv` author here: reinstall the library as a dev dependency

```
npm i -D react-native-dotenv
```

Answer (score -1):

No, fs is not available in React Native.  You can use the react-native-fs package instead.

https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs